# Map list of multiple substrings in PySpark

Tags: string, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, substring

I have a dataframe with one column like this:

| Locations |
| --- |
| Germany:city_Berlin |
| France:town_Montpellier |
| Italy:village_Amalfi |

I would like to get rid of the substrings: 'city_', 'town_', 'village_', etc.

So the output should be:

| Locations |
| --- |
| Germany:Berlin |
| France:tMontpellier |
| Italy:Amalfi |

I can get rid of one of them this way:
`F.regexp_replace('Locations', 'city_', '')`

Is there a similar way to pass several substrings to remove from the original column?

Ideally I'm looking for a one line solution, without having to create separate functions or convoluted things.

Comment: The substring that I need to remove can sometimes have more than one word, separated with underscore.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `sometimes have more than one word, separated with underscore`? One row might look like 1. `Italy:village_Amalfi,Italy:city_Rome` or 2. `Italy:village_Amalfi,city_Rome`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I went with this solution:

```
df = df.withColumn('Locations', F.regexp_replace('Locations', '(city_)|(town_)|(village_)', ''))
```

I wasn't aware that I could include several search strings in the regexp_replace function.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt map. Looks to me like you want to replace strings immediately to the left of `:` if they end with `_`. If so use  regex. Code below

```
df.withColumn('new_Locations', regexp_replace('Locations', '(?<=\:)[a-z_]+','')).show(truncate=False)


+---+-----------------------+------------------+
|id |Locations              |new_Locations     |
+---+-----------------------+------------------+
|1  |Germany:city_Berlin    |Germany:Berlin    |
|2  |France:town_Montpellier|France:Montpellier|
|4  |Italy:village_Amalfi   |Italy:Amalfi      |
+---+-----------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: What if it's not just one word? In some cases I have several words separated by underscore that I would like to remove, hence the map idea.

Comment: Your sample data set wasn't representative

Answer (score 0):

```
F.regexp_replace('Locations', r'(?<=:).*_', '')
```

`.*` tells that you will match all characters. But it is located between `(?<=:)` and `_`.

`_` is the symbol which must follow all the characters matched by `.*`.

`(?<=:)` is a syntax for "positive lookbehind". It is not a part of a match, but it ensures that right before the `.*_` you must have a `:` symbol.

---

Another option - list of strings to remove

`strings = ['city', 'big_city', 'town', 'big_town', 'village']`

```py
F.regexp_replace('Locations', fr"(?<=:)({'|'.join(strings)})_", '')
```

---

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('Germany:big_city_Berlin',),
     ('France:big_town_Montpellier',),
     ('Italy:village_Amalfi',)],
    ['Locations'])

df = df.withColumn('loc1', F.regexp_replace('Locations', r'(?<=:).*_', ''))

strings = ['city', 'big_city', 'town', 'big_town', 'village']
df = df.withColumn('loc2', F.regexp_replace('Locations', fr"(?<=:)({'|'.join(strings)})_", ''))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
# |Locations                  |loc1              |loc2              |
# +---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
# |Germany:big_city_Berlin    |Germany:Berlin    |Germany:Berlin    |
# |France:big_town_Montpellier|France:Montpellier|France:Montpellier|
# |Italy:village_Amalfi       |Italy:Amalfi      |Italy:Amalfi      |
# +---------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: What if it's not just one word? In some cases I have several words separated by underscore that I would like to remove, hence the map idea.

Comment: @Jaol - It would work, as the regex will look for the last underscore. But I have added an option with a list of strings to replace, if you want to opt for it.